# Pass static Action as parameter

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is:

```
public static Action<string> action_thread_ended { get; private set; }

public static void action_set(Action<string> target, Action<string> source)
{
    target += source;
}
```

Usage (from different class)

```
MyClassName.action_set(MyClassName.action_thread_ended, Console.WriteLine);
```

Result: Nothing

I am of course trying to do this to prevent having to make an `action_set` function for each Action in the class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are immutable.

`target += source` creates a new delegate instance, and makes the `target` parameter refer to it.
The property that you passed is not affected.

Comment: Yes I realized that, and am now looking for a way to get this to work.

Comment: By 'get this to work' I mean I am looking for a function that allows the parent class of the Action<> to add methods to it, without explicitly defining that Action<> inside the function. So an external class picks the Action<> of the parent class it wants to add a method to, and then the parent class does `action+=method;`. This prevents any external class from overriding all of the Action's methods by doing `action=method;` while still not forcing me to create a new set-function in the parent for each Action<>. There is no way to do this? (And sorry for my poor explenation.)

Comment: You should just create an `event`, which does exactly that.

Comment: Isn't it so that with an `event` any one class can actually do `event=method` instead of `event+=method` effectively removing any previous method added to it? Which is exactly what I wanted to prevent doing this.

Comment: @natli no, events can only use += or -=  So only events can only be removed if the remover has a reference to the event handler or method assigned.  EDIT: nevermind... you _can_ set null to events.  At least in LinqPad

Comment: @natli don't thank me yet, I went to whip together a quick example in LINQPad, and I could nullify the event.

Comment: @natli Ahh, figured it out.  It can be set to `null` (essentially wiping out the listener list) from _within the declaring class_.  Not even subclasses can nullify it.  So other classes can _only_ use +=/-= but when you try to set to null, it throws a compiler error!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Awesome, thanks for testing that ;) Looks like events are exactly what I need indeed.